# Ubuntu 18.04, complex network configuration with Netplan

Tags: networking, netplan

I have a system on which I am using Netplan to provide networking and am running into some issues with the configuration.

When I boot the box, there is not networking.  When I try to run `netplan apply`, I get

```
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 26 column 18: expected sequence
```

Which doesn't make sense, because line 26, column 18 is the ":" after "managementbr0":

```
bridges: 
  managementbro:
```

Why is a sequence expected there?  Here is my full 01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
    eth1:
      dhcp4: no
    ib0:
      addresses: [ x.x.x.x/24 ]
      mtu: 65520
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [ eth0, eth1 ]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
  vlans:
    bond0.229:
      id: 229
      link: bond0
    bond0.228:
      id: 228
      link: bond0
  bridges:
    managementbr0:
      interfaces: bond0
      addresses: [ x.x.x.x/22 ]
      nameservers:
        search: [ foobar.net ]
        addresses: [ x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x ]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 9
        hello-time: 2
        max-age: 12
        stp: false
      routes:
        - to: x.x.x.x/8
          via: x.x.x.x
    br0:
      addresses: [ x.x.x.x/22 ]
      interfaces: bond0.229
      gateway4: x.x.x.x
      nameservers:
        search: [ foobar.net ]
        addresses: [ x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x ]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 9
        hello-time: 2
        max-age: 12
        stp: false
    br1:
      interfaces: bond0.228
      parameters:
          forward-delay: 9
          hello-time: 2
          max-age: 12
          stp: false
```

What's odd is that, on a similar system with similar hardware, this configuration works at boot time, however on that very same system that works at boot time, if I run `netplan generate` or `netplan apply`, I get that same error `Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 26 column 18: expected sequence`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, instead of editing your post to say how you solved it, you may want to consider writing your own answer to your question explaining how you solved it and then accept your own answer.  (I have copied your solution into an answer so you can accept it if you wish, and I've done it such that I won't gain rep from that answer, but it would be beneficial to answer your own questions instead when you solve them, for the future.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From OP's edits:

> I fixed this by wrapping my interfaces in brackets "[" "]"